# Javascript - Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why am I getting: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined**?
I want to get the day, month and year from a "task" so then I can calculate how many days are left to hand in the task, but I get that error.

```
<div class="task" id="task">
                <ul>
                    <li class="title" id="@ta.Id"><div class="complete"></div>@ta.Title</li>
                    <li class="body"><b>Project: </b>@ta.Description</li>
                    <li>Hand In: @ta.Dia/@ta.Mes/@ta.Año</li>
                    <li class="leftion">Days left: </li>
                    <li class="day" style="display: none">@ta.Day</li>
                    <li class="month" style="display: none">@ta.Month</li>
                    <li class="year" style="display: none">@ta.Year</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var today = new Date();
     var dd = today.getDate();
     var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!

     var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
     if (dd < 10) {
         dd = '0' + dd
     }
     if (mm < 10) {
         mm = '0' + mm
     }
     var firstDate = new Date(yyyy, mm, dd);
     var gio = document.getElementsByClassName("task");
     var lele = document.getElementsByClassName("leftion");
     for (var i = 0; i <= gio.length; i++) {
         var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
         var day= document.getElementsByClassName("day")[i].innerHTML;
```

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined**

```
        var month = document.getElementsByClassName("month")[i].innerHTML;
        var year= document.getElementsByClassName("year")[i].innerHTML;
         var secondDate = new Date(year, month, day);


         var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime()) / (oneDay)));
         lele[i].innerHTML = diffDays;
     }
</script>
```

Comment: That error message simply means that you're trying to access a property ("innerHTML") of a value that's `undefined`.  Step one is to look at all the places you're using `.innerHTML` and determine which *might* result in `undefined`.

Comment: I pointed out where the problem is from the whole code. it is the line just above message that devides the two fragments of code

Comment: `i < gio.length` instead of `i <= gio.length`.

Comment: You're welcome. It's a typical off-by-one error. However your question is not the right form for SO, so it will be closed soon I am afraid. I hope you aren't going to be annoyed.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have more `.task` nodes than `.day` nodes in your html

You'll have more chance to find your bugs and avoid lots of strange behaviour if you look for the day only in the nodes in the current `.task` node:

```
var gio = document.getElementsByClassName("task");
//...
for (var i = 0; i <= gio.length; i++) {
    //...
    var taskNode = gio[i];
    var day = taskNode.getElementsByClassName("day")[0].innerHTML;
```

See the use of `gio[i].getElementsByClassName`, not `document.getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score -1):

When you use the loop `for (var i = 0; i <= gio.length; i++) {...}`, `gio.length` === 1, which means the loop will run twice.

So, when `i` === 1, `document.getElementsByClassName("day")[i]` is `undefined` as you have only one "day" class element.

Change `i <= gio.length` to `i < gio.length` or refactor the code generally.